# Drupal Views: How to remove 1 item if it matches the Node TItle

Tags: views

I'm trying to remove one item from a block view if the CCK node title of that item matches the node title of the page it is appearing on.  Can someone tell me how I would achieve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better and easier to match by Node ID. To do that, add a "Node: NID" argument (or a 'contextual filter' in newer Views versions) to your view, set it to "Provide default argument", choose "Node ID from URL" as default argument type and check the "Exclude the argument" box. That should do the trick.